# Confirm that two filesystems are identical, ignoring special files

Tags: linux, diff, duplicate, tree, deduplication

/media/A and /media/B should be identical, but I want to confirm before deleting one.

Duplicate file finders don't work, because they'll find two copies of the same file within B, for instance.  I only want to confirm that every file in one is identical to the other.

`diff -qr /media/A/ /media/B/` seems to work, but the output is cluttered with garbage like

> diff: /media/A//etc/alternatives/ControlPanel: No such file or directory

and

> File /media/A//dev/tty8 is a character special file while file /media/B//dev/tty8 is a character special file

I can suppress the former with `2> /dev/null`, but I don't know about the latter.

`rsync -avn /media/A/ /media/B/` also produces a bunch of clutter, like "skipping non-regular file".

How can I compare the two trees and just make sure that all the real files exist in both and are identical?

Comment: You don't mention the operating system. I'm guessing that it is some linux/unix variant, so your message might get more responses if it was tagged as such. However, if I was doing this in Windows, I would use one of my favourite tools Beyond Compare (from http://www.scootersoftware.com/) which also has a linux version. This isn't free, but there is 30 day trial. The only other way that I know would be to pipe the diff output to a file and then try to strip out the irrelevant lines until it gets to a manageable size. You can use sed to do this or is it awk? (It's been years since I use either)

Answer (score 2):

Using this following command should check to see if they are identical.

```
diff imageA imageB -r 2> /dev/null | grep -v "is a character special file" | grep -v "is a block special file" && echo "viola"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Guiffy.  It's not free, but has a 21 day free trial, which doesn't limit functionality :

[Guiffy home page](http://www.guiffy.com/Folder-Compare.html)

[Full (massive) list of features](http://www.guiffy.com/features.html)

It claims to do the following, and seems to be very close to what you are looking for, or may get close enough that you can take it from there:

- Folder Compare works with Unicode file/folder names
- Folder Compare works with archive files (.zip, .tar, .jar, and others).
- Save compare reports - the Guiffy folder compare tool generates reports as HTML
- Quickly launches a file compare from the folder compare.
- User friendly folder compare view with Explorer-like interface and expandable sub-folders.
- Folder Compare interface includes popup menus for file synchronization operations.
- Recursive compare option - folder compare can do a file tree compare.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync in write mode (with `-v`/`--verbose` and without `-n`/`--dry-run`), and run it a few times until the output stabilises. Run it as root so that recreating non-regular files (implied by -D and -a) works, which should get rid of the clutter.